# Перевод даты с указанием временной зоны к нужному формату в Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Имеется данный DataFrame:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перевести дату из столбца 'server_time' в формат '2021-05-09 23:58:18' без указания часового пояса? Пробую вот так:

```
data['server_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['server_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Меняется формат столбца на datetime64[ns, UTC], но часовой пояс не убирается. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
data['server_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['server_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tz_localize(None)
```

Comment: passant, вот спасибо Вам за помощь. Единственное только что перед .tz_localize(None) нужно добавить dt. Решилось вот таким кодом:
data['server_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['server_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').dt.tz_localize(None)

Comment: @Николай Ершов  1. На самом деле добавление префикса "dt." нужно не всегда. Но если у вас так заработало - и отлично. 2. Вам, как новичку на этом сайте, подсказываю: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answer